# jquery validation according database field size

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

for example in database column1 having data type varchar and size 200,how do I check this size(200) for validation in java script.

Comment: Share the attempts you have made so far

Comment: MySQL is server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read some simple java script validation tutorial like
http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/javascript-sample-registration-form-validation.php and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_form_validations.htm

```
var col1 = $(document).getElementById('#yourInputFieldId').value;
if(col1.length > 200)
{
   alert("Invalid Value");
}
```